# Qt tutorials for beginners

Tags: c++, qt

I want to ask about resources for learning `Qt` for **beginners**. What resources do you recommend for that?

Answer (score 26):

Have also a look at the [Qt programming videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KtOzh0StTc&list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63&spfreload=10) on *VoidRealms*' Youtube channel.

Answer (score 9):

The transition from C++ to QT may seem bit awkward at first. But don't be afraid its somewhat easier than c++ when you get more familiar with it.

To start of I would like to recommend the first few videos of
[voidRealms youvideos on c++ QT](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KtOzh0StTc&playnext=1&list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63&feature=results_main) to get a feel on QT framework. All of them are really good. Try to do the examples by your own. You will be quite comfortable with the framework after watching these videos.

Next if possible try to refer [Foundations of Qt Development (Expert's Voice in Open Source)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598318) which is also a very good reference for QT.
After going through few chapters you will be very accustomed to the Framework.

Reading C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 which is a usually recommended book will look good if you have this basic background on QT.

I would also like to recommend the On-line Reference Documentation which will give a great depth in to QT when  going forward.

Answer (score 4):

As a recently beginner to Qt as well, along with the link Nawaz provided (which is where you should go to find all the info about all of Qt's different classes) I found the following links helpful as well:

[Qt Examples and Tutorials](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html)

[C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4 book (if you look you can find this book free to read on a handful of sites)](http://www.google.com/search?q=qt%20tutorial&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&source=hp&q=C%2b%2b%20GUI%20Programming%20with%20Qt%204&aq=f&aqi=g2g-s1g2&aql=f&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=2b11957ef3c551f6)

Along with these, depending on your OS, you should download Qt Creator, its a great tool to begin learning how Qt works and how the different classes interact

Answer (score 3):

QT course material by Nokia should be helpful as a fast introduction to QT
http://qt.nokia.com/services-partners/qt-in-education/qt-in-education-course-material

Answer (score 2):

Try:

http://sector.ynet.sk/qt4-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu **QT creator** is available, and it contains lot of examples - although I don't know about Windows. I learned about QT with QT creator.