# Learning Qt by example

Tags: c++, qt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Qt tutorials for beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734253/qt-tutorials-for-beginners)

What resources for learning `Qt` by example do you recommend?

Thanks.

Comment: -1 for creating duplicate topic within 19 mins!

Answer (score 2):

If you install the [Qt SDK](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/), Qt Creator will have a comprehensive and structured list of examples right when you start it, selectable from a menu.

Answer (score 2):

[C++ GUI Programming with Qt4](http://www.amazon.ca/GUI-Programming-Qt4-Jasmin-Blanchette/dp/0132354160/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1303322081&sr=8-1)

Comment: I have this book and can confirm it's one of the best to learn Qt