# open window to choose images c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using c++ in ubuntu 12.04 using gcc. Am trying to perform few image processing tasks using opencv. For this, I want the user to select an image. Is it possible to open the directory explorer through c++, and let user choose the image, by selecting folders or drives, etc.? I actually did not know how to google this question exactly, my apologies if this is pretty rudimentary. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use a GUI toolkit like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/). They ususally have some sort of function for what you want. In the case of Qt the [QFileDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qfiledialog.html) would be good.

For learning Qt: There are [official tutorials](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/qtexamplesandtutorials.html) or maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734253/qt-tutorials-for-beginners).

If you want to go down this route you can also use a completely separate program just for getting a file name. Something like [zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/file-selection.html.en) maybe. Which platform do you want to do this on?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does this mean I have to compile my code using QT? Can you please detail some more?

Comment: It is actually quite complicated since Qt is a full fledged GUI toolkit intended for creating graphical applications. I added some links to tutorials.

Comment: I seem to recall that OpenCV has some examples with graphical user interfaces. Might be helpful to look at those, too.